# Keras callback ReduceLROnPlateau - cooldown parameter

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, callback, keras

`ReduceLROnPlateau` callback in Keras seems to be an interesting tool to use in training models. But I could not really figure out exactly what the `cooldown` parameter means in the callback function `ReduceLROnPlateau` in Keras.

Here is what the documentation says:

First, the interface of the function:

```
keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', 
                                  factor=0.1, 
                                  patience=10, 
                                  verbose=0, 
                                  mode='auto', 
                                  min_delta=0.0001, 
                                  cooldown=0, 
                                  min_lr=0)
```

`ReduceLROnPlateau`: Models often benefit from reducing the learning rate by a factor of 2-10 once learning stagnates. This callback monitors a quantity and if no improvement is seen for a 'patience' number of epochs, the learning rate is reduced.

`cooldown`: number of epochs to wait before resuming normal operation after lr has been reduced.

The explanation does not really make it clear to me. Is it meant here that:
- Say that `lr=A`. And the learning rate is reduced if the relevant monitored metric does not improve during `patience` number of epochs. (And say that `lr=B` after reducing it.)
- And the learning rate is set to its first value (`lr=A` again) after `cooldown` number of epochs.

Is my understanding correct? If not, what is the real function of cooldown parameter here?

PS. When I google it, I see some examples where people set the `cooldown` parameter to zero, which makes me think that my perception on this parameter is wrong.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

True, it does not state it clearly in the description. What it means is that if you set a cooldown you have to wait before resuming normal operation (i.e. beginning to monitor if there is any improvement in the monitored metric over a `patience` epochs).

For example, let's say `cooldown=5`. After the learning rate is reduced, the algorithm waits `5` epochs before starting to monitor the metrics again. So if there is no improvement in the metric and `patience=10`, the learning rate will be reduced again after `15` epochs.

You can confirm this by looking at the corresponding [code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L1075).

Comment: Great explanation! In your exmaple, am I getting it right now that the lr is reduced every 15th epoch as long as there is no improvement in the monitored metric? (Meaning that the lr cannot be reduced "again" quicker than completing 15 epochs.)

Comment: Yes, and over the first `5`  epochs (or as many epochs as `cooldown` dictates) the metric isn't even being monitored.

Comment: So effectively this just modifies the patience, but lets you use a different (shorter) patience for the first time it runs?

Comment: @Ataxias yes, but it can be (and usually is) longer than the patience. It makes sense if you think about it. You want your model to first somewhat converge on the high learning rate before reducing it and letting it converge even further.

Comment: @Djib2011 Thanks. I think we are saying the same thing. If you have a patience of P and cooldown of C steps/epochs, then to have a first learning rate reduction you wait (at a minimum) P, and after that you wait C+P, which is always > P. You additionally say that it makes sense to use C > P, which I think is often reasonable.

Comment: One additional qualitative difference using cooldown (besides modifying the effective patience) I think is the following: after reducing the learning rate, by using a cooldown you anticipate that there might be a temporary improvement in the monitored metric, but you choose to ignore it (since monitoring has stopped) - you are instead interested in the long-term convergence.